# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre setMaxResults y setFetchSize en org.hibernate.Query? (Traducción)

Tags: java, hibernate

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el método `setMaxResults` y el método `setFetchSize` de org.hibernate.Query?

Puedes ver la pregunta original [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087728/what-is-difference-between-setmaxresults-and-setfetchsize-in-org-hibernate-query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**setMaxResults** tiene el mismo efecto sobre la consulta que `LIMIT` en *SQL*, es decir, limita el número máximo de filas que devuelve la consulta.

**setFetchSize** tiene más que ver con la optimización, pues permite indicar a *Hibernate* cómo devolver los datos en bloques de información (todos los registros a la vez, o bloques de *n* registros conforme necesitemos acceder a los datos). Hay que tener en cuenta que `setFetchSize` no está implementado para todos los drivers de bases de datos.

Puedes ver la respuesta original [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087728/what-is-difference-between-setmaxresults-and-setfetchsize-in-org-hibernate-query/6087815#6087815)